# Export to CSV using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, sharepoint, powershell-3.0

I'm using a PowerShell script to grab the root site URL and all the subsites within the SharePoint site and outputting the URL, title and total users as shown below.

```
Url: http://sourcevideo.f.com | Title: The Source Video | Users: 3345
Url: http://sourcevideo.f.com/AGap | Title: A Gap | Users: 3345
Url: http://sourcevideo.f.com/AVideos | Title: Videos | Users: 417
Url: http://sourcevideo.f.com/BCt | Title: BC Japan | Users: 39
```

How would I be able to export that to a CSV with three columns?

Code:

```bsh
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$SiteCollections = Get-SPWebApplication "http://sourcevideo.f.com" |
                   Get-SPSite -Limit All
foreach ($Site in $SiteCollections) {
    foreach ($Web in $Site.AllWebs) {
        Write-Host "Url:"$web.URL "| Title:"$web.Title "| Users:" $web.AllUsers.Count
    }
    Write-Host ""
}
```

Comment: the usual way is to make a new object with the wanted properties, then use the `Export-CSV` cmdlet to create the CSV for you. that cmdlet is designed to accept a collection of objects and turn it into a proper CSV file.

Comment: Your ouput is a csv with `|` as delimiter. It would work just to replace them with an other delimiter and to save it as .csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the outer foreach to a variable and
in the inner one build a [PSCustomObject]

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$SiteCollections = Get-SPWebApplication "http://sourcevideo.f.com" |
                   Get-SPSite -Limit All
$Data = foreach ($Site in $SiteCollections) {
    foreach ($Web in $Site.AllWebs) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Url   = $web.URL
            Title = $web.Title
            Users = $web.AllUsers.Count
        }
    }
}
$Data | Export-Csv .\yourName.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks so much LotPings! Works like a charm, is there a object to display the DisplayNames of the Users? So instead of getting the AllUsers.Count, is there a name option?

Comment: In general use the `Get-Member` cmdlet to show available methods and properties of an object by piping to it  I.E. `Get-ChildItem -File| Get-Member`, I don't have a Sharepoint site here so I can't do it for you.

Comment: No that's totally ok, I'm in the process of learning also! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Lee's answer, the code would look like this:

```
$WebInfo = @(
“$web.url”
“$web.title”
"$web.allusers.count"
)
$properties = @{'website url'=$WebInfo[0];'website title'=$WebInfo[1];'user count'=$WebInfo[2]}
$WebsiteObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $properties
$WebsiteObject | Export-Csv -path "put path here" -NoTypeInformation
```

I have not tested this.

Comment: Please avoid using smart quotes `“ ”`, even though PS can handle them it's not good practice to use them. Just stick with normal double quotes `" "`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to create a new object

```
New-Object PSObject -Property @{Url=$web.URL;Title=$web.Title;Users=$web.AllUsers.Count}
```

Here is a completed script i wrote but can test as i dont have the sharepoint plugin

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$SiteCollections = Get-SPWebApplication "http://sourcevideo.f.com" | Get-SPSite -Limit All | %{
    $Site = $_
    $Site | %{
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{Url=$_.URL;Title=$_.Title;Users=$_.AllUsers.Count}
    }
} | export-csv -Path C:\Test\Output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You don't iterate the `.Allwebs` property ? And assign the whole pipe to a var and at the same time end with `Export-Csv`? The var will be empty. Better avoid aliases in answers.